# Stack implementation using arrays java

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I am unable to implement stack using array in Java through this code  as my *push()* is unable to store value in the array...

**UseStack**

```
class UseStack{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of Stack....");
        int n = obj.nextInt();
        new Stack(n);
        while(true){
            System.out.println("1: Push");
            System.out.println("2: Show");
            int choice = obj.nextInt();;
            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                Push push = new Push(n);
                push.push();
                break;
                case 2:
                Push push1 = new Push(n);
                push1.show();
                break;
                default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Option");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Stack.java**

```
class Stack {
    public int arr[];
    public  int top;
    public  int capacity;

    Stack(int size){
        this.arr = new int[size];
        this.capacity = size;
        this.top = -1;
    }
}
```

**Push.java**

```
class Push extends Stack {
    Push(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    private static Scanner obj;
    public void push(){
        obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Value to push...");
        int value = obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Value : "+value);
        if(top==capacity-1){
            System.out.println("StackOverflow");
            return;
        }
        else{
            top++;
            System.out.println("Top : "+top);
            arr[top]=value;
            System.out.println("Pushed... "+arr[top]);
        }
    }

    public void show(){
        if(top==-1){
            System.out.println("StackUnderFlow");
            return;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Stack Elements : ");
            for(int i=top;i>=0;i--){
                System.out.println(arr[i]+" ");
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Please excuse my ignorance , there may be some other better ways to implement stack i.e.. using Java's builtin Stack as i have succesfully implemented using through this but now i am trying to implement by creating different classes for each method..

**Problem : **

```
Enter the size of Stack....
3
1: Push
2: Show
1
Enter Value to push...
5
Value : 5
Top : 0
Pushed... 5
1: Push
2: Show
1
Enter Value to push...
10
Value : 10
Top : 0
Pushed... 10
1: Push
2: Show
2
StackUnderFlow
1: Push
2: Show
```

As you can see that my top value is incremented only one time and it becomes 0 from -1 and my values are not storing in the array as every time after pushing some element i want to see elements using *show()* it shows *StackUnderflow*

This problem is seems very hard me to locate why this is happening every time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new object every time when push and show in switch case, then always top is initialized by -1 before operation

```
case 1:
Push push = new Push(n);
push.push();
break;
case 2:
Push push1 = new Push(n);
push1.show();
break;
```

Create one object and do operation on that object only

```
class UseStack{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of Stack....");
        int n = obj.nextInt();
        Push push = new Push(n); // Create one object
        while(true){
            System.out.println("1: Push");
            System.out.println("2: Show");
            int choice = obj.nextInt();;
            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                push.push(); // Then do operation on that object
                break;
                case 2:
                push.show(); // Then do operation on that object
                break;
                default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Option");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ItazakhStern moving show() means ? And I don't say to move. Remove the object creation from swich case and create outside loop so that you  can do operation on same object

Comment: I got it sir i mean to say that show() can be initialised by push.show() instead of push1.show()

Comment: Sir i have created Pop.java class in which pop()method is defined and class Pop extends Push, but pop() is not working.So i think Pop also needs to extends Stack for working but Multi_Inheritance is not supported

Comment: @ItazakhStern Create an another post with details about your problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62728760/stack-implementation-java

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you have a design problem. `Stack` is indeed a class and represent stack objects. But push is only an action on a stack, and thus should be a direct method of the `Stack` class, along with `show` and `pop`. My advice would be to also implement a method giving the current size, or at least testing whether the stack is empty.

And in OO programming, you should create one single `Stack` object and use methods on it. That is not all. Single concern is a best practice, so reading should not be a task of the `Stack` class: it should only be concerned by storing objects and giving them back. So I would move the Scanner and the questions to ask to the UseStack class.