# Stack implementation java

Tags: java, stack

Unable to implement stack through this code...

**UseStack.java**

```
     class UseStack{
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter the size of Stack....");
                int n = obj.nextInt();
                Push push = new Push(n);
                Pop pop = new Pop(n);
                while(true){
                    System.out.println("1: Push");
                    System.out.println("2: pop");
                    System.out.println("3: Show");
                    int choice = obj.nextInt();;
                    switch(choice){
                        case 1:
                        push.push();
                        break;
                        case 2:
                        pop.pop();
                        break;
                        case 3:
                        push.show();    
                        break;
                        default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid Option");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Stack.java**

```
class Stack {
    public int arr[];
    public  int top;
    public  int capacity;

    Stack(int size){
        this.arr = new int[size];
        this.capacity = size;
        this.top = -1;
    }
}
```

**Push.java**

```
class Push extends Stack {
    Push(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    private static Scanner obj;
    public void push(){
        obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Value to push...");
        int value = obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Value : "+value);
        if(top==capacity-1){
            System.out.println("StackOverflow");
            return;
        }
        else{
            top++;
            System.out.println("Top : "+top);
            arr[top]=value;
            System.out.println("Pushed... "+arr[top]);
        }
    }

    public void show(){
        if(top==-1){
            System.out.println("StackUnderFlow");
            return;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Stack Elements : ");
            for(int i=top;i>=0;i--){
                System.out.println(arr[i]+" ");
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

**Pop.java**

```
public class Pop extends Stack {

    Pop(int size) {
        super(size);
    }
    
    public void pop(){
        if(top==-1){
            System.out.println("StackUnderflow-pop");
            return;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Top : "+top);
            System.out.println("Poped.. "+arr[top]);
            top--;
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Problem**

In this implementation pop() is not working.....

I think for this Pop class needs to extends both Stack and Push classes as so this is not possible in java ,If I'm wrong can anyone help me with this how to resolved it...

Comment: Why would push and pop, which are *operations*, extend the `Stack` class? You wouldn't write `Dog extends Animal` and `Bark extends Dog`, would you?

Comment: @Kayaman sir can you correct me more

Comment: You don't need to call me sir. I'm just asking you why do you have `Push` and `Pop` classes? Why don't the `push()` and `pop()` methods exist in the `Stack` class?

Comment: @kayaman  there is no error when i have both push () and pop() in Stack but i want to know about why this causing error

Comment: You need to include any errors you get in the question. But the code is wrong by design, so you should first fix your design (remove `Push` and `Pop` classes), and then try to get your code to work.

Comment: The problem is that pushing and popping aren't working on the same data structure.  When the user gives a "push" command,  you call `push()` on the `push` stack and the data thus gets added to the `push` stack; meanwhile the 'pop` stack is still empty.  Now when the user gives a "pop" command, you call the `pop()` method of the `pop` stack, and there's nothing to pop from the empty `pop` stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop()` is not working because you are using different objects for push and pop.

You don't need to define another class for push and pop, they are operation add those function inside Stack class.

```
class Stack {
   ... // members and constructor
   public void push(){..}
   public void pop(){..}
   public void show(){..}
}
```

And create an object of Stack class and use for push, pop and show

```
Stack s = new Stack(n);
while(true){
    ... 
    switch(choice){
        case 1:
        s.push();
        break;
        case 2:
        s.pop();
        break;
        case 3:
        s.show();    
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Option");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ItazakhStern knew what? That because of your completely wrong design, you're actually using multiple objects and yet you think you can treat them as if they were a single stack? I suggest you start reading the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), because you don't know as much as you think you do.

Comment: @ItazakhStern: "I know this"? If you knew it, why ask the question?

Comment: I mean to say that operations like push and pop can be defined in stack class